# How to narrow types of params when using lambda in typescript？

Tags: typescript, lambda, type-narrowing

like this:

```
[count, sizeType, sourceType].reduce((previousValue: number|string[], currentValue: number|string[]) => ('number'===typeof currentValue && currentValue || (<string[]>currentValue).length)&&{...previousValue as object, currentValue} || {...previousValue as object})
```

I want to extract params which assign to the rules`number && !==0  or  array && array.length!==0` 
But I got this error
[image]

Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide sample input and output  ?

Comment: The problem here is that your arguments can be either number or a string but your lambda can return an object which doesn't match type constraint for `previousValue`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it